# Find repeat polygons in SpatVector dataframe

Tags: r, spatial, terra

I'm using a global database of geometries for a project, but some of them are repeated, and the identifying columns (other than the geometry) are sometimes the same and sometimes different in these repeated shapes (for example, when one shape is governed by two bodies, it will be in the dataset twice, with the governing body column containing one value in each row). Is there an easy way to find repeated geometries in a SpatVector dataframe? I am new to Terra.

I want to do something like this...

```
terra_df %>%
    group_by(SHAPE) %>%
    add_count()
```

...in order to see how many times each shape is repeated in the dataframe, regardless of the other columns, which may be the same and may be different. But I can't do this becuase it appears that in `terra`, the SHAPE column is not accessible(?) like it would be in an sf dataframe.

reprex:

```
library(terra)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v2 <- v %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  mutate(NAME_1 = "Diekirch1",
         NAME_2 = "Some other name")
# here, I'm manually repeating one row in the dataset, but slightly changing some of the non-shape columns. 

v3 <- rbind(v, v2)

# view the repeated shape
ggplot() +
  geom_spatvector(data = v3,
                  fill = "purple",
                  alpha = .5)

# goal is to find what shape is repeated
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the geometry with `geom`

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v2 <- v[1,]
v2$NAME1 = "Diekirch1"
v2$NAME2 = "Some other name"
v3 <- rbind(v, v2)

#plot(v3, col = "purple", alpha = .5)

g <- geom(v3, wkt=TRUE)
duplicated(g)
table(as.integer(as.factor(g)))
table(v3$NAME_1)
```

You can use `unique` to remove duplicate geometries.